# my list (Recyclerview) displays on multiple screens want to change the background colour of list item on only one screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-drawable

This is my viewholderClass which displays the list on multiple screen.

```
 class TagViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: RecyclerViewItemClickListener?,isTraining: Boolean) : BaseViewHolder<AdapterTag>(itemView, listener) {
        override fun onBindView(context: Context, data: AdapterTag ) {
            itemView.tag_icon.setImageResource(data.getIconResId())
            itemView.tag_name.text = data.getTitle()
            itemView.tag_count.text = "[${data.getItemCount()}]"
//background color change of selected item in list
            itemView.isSelected = (data.getItemCount() == 0)
        }
    }
```

this is my drawable class which implements in below drawable class for background colour change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/card_radius" />
            <padding android:bottom="@dimen/card_vertical_padding"
                android:left="@dimen/card_horizontal_padding"
                android:right="@dimen/card_horizontal_padding"
                android:top="@dimen/card_vertical_padding" />
            <solid android:color="@color/cardBackgroundWithZeroItem"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

this is my list background class which changes the background colour in selected_state.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/training_tag_card_state"/>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/card_radius" />
                <padding android:bottom="@dimen/card_vertical_padding"
                    android:left="@dimen/card_horizontal_padding"
                    android:right="@dimen/card_horizontal_padding"
                    android:top="@dimen/card_vertical_padding" />
                <solid android:color="@color/cardBackground"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

My recycler view list displays on multiple screen but i have to change the **background color of list items only on particular screen** but in the tagViewHolder it changes background color of list items on everyscreen ***how to use the isTraining:Boolean(it is for my screen i want to change background color of list items) such that i can use background color on desired screen of list items***.what should i change in implemetations to get the solution of above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pass any value to the adapter from the activity. Based on that Boolean value you have changed the background.

Comment: here isTraining is unused and how to use this to get desired results(such that i can use background color on desired screen of list items)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass isTraining Boolean value through adapter

For ex : You have 2 Activities

A and B  , You want change the List Item Background in A Activity only for that u need to pass the   isTraining value True

```
   if (isTraining) {
        itemView.parentView.background =
            ContextCompact.getDrawable(itemView.parentView.context, R.drawable.resourceid)
    } else {
        //Default value
        ContextCompact.getDrawable(itemView.parentView.context, R.drawable.resourceid)
    }
```

Comment: Problem is that i have 2 different adapter for both the 2  screens (BAse adapter for both the adapters)and one main adapter for the itemCount and different listItem types , so i came out with solution but i dont know how to implement it
1. Add (isTraining) it to the argument of the constructor(TagViewHolder) and pass it (hold it as a member variable and refer to it when executing bindView ())
2. Add to the argument of bindView () and pass

Answer (score 0):

```
class TagViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: RecyclerViewItemClickListener?,private val isTraining:Boolean) : BaseViewHolder<AdapterTag>(itemView, listener) {
    override fun onBindView(context: Context, data: AdapterTag) {
        itemView.tag_icon.setImageResource(data.getIconResId())
        itemView.tag_name.text = data.getTitle()
        itemView.tag_count.text = "[${data.getItemCount()}]"
        itemView.isSelected = (data.getItemCount() == 0) && isTraining
    }
}
```

declaring a private variable and providing it in a condition "isTraining".
using this variable in parent class to define the condition true for the particular screen adapter.